# Rancher x509 Certificate Expired yet not

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

When running kubectl, I get the error

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2021-10-05T11:59:14-04:00 is after 2021-09-29T19:21:40Z
```

So clearly it says the cert is expired.  Only problem is I'm not sure which cert it is.

I've checked

- HAProxy (Rancher sits behind L7 HAProxy with LE cert)
- Certs in the secrets shown from `sudo k3s kubectl get secrets -n cattle-system`
- Certs in `/etc/kubernetes/ssl` on the K8s node

All are fine (not expired), as this particular rancher/k8s instance was brought up in June, so all the certs are only a few months old, and expire either 1 year or 10 years later.

So what cert is expired that needs to be updated?

Some information about my setup:

- Rancher 2.5.9 HA (K3s v1.21.1+k3s1) (single-node, Ubuntu 20.04)
- Kubernetes 1.20.9-rancher1-1 (single-node, Control plane/Worker/etcd, Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Have you checked the cert that is usually embedded in your kubeconfig? And have you actually _looked_ at the cert being returned, as in `echo '' | openssl s_client -servername whatever.example.com -showcerts -connect whatever.example.com:6443 | openssl x509 -noout -text` kind of deal?

Comment: @mdaniel yes, they are all valid.  And I just did.  The cert returned by that command is `/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem`.

Comment: @cclloyd Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Adam the LE cert was invalid because one of the root certs was invalid.  Had to update root cert packages on host systems and regenerated cert.

Comment: Hi @cclloyd Could you post an answer, since it would be better for other users to see that you found the solution and also for indexing the answer by the site?

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

Based on information from comments

**Root cause:**

One of the root certificates is invalid. This caused the Let's Encrypt certificate to be invalid.

**Solution:**

1. Update root cert packages on host systems
2. Regenerate certificate